# Customize Billing Address List in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, address, billing

Below is list.html file for Billing address.
Which contains dropdown with addressOptions.

```
<div class="field field-select-billing">
<label class="label"><span data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
<div class="control" data-bind="if: (addressOptions.length > 1)">
    <select class="select" name="billing_address_id" data-bind="
    options: addressOptions,
    optionsText: addressOptionsText,
    value: selectedAddress,
    event: {change: onAddressChange(selectedAddress())};
"></select>
</div>
```

I want to use radio button instead of drop-down then how can i achieve?
Or how can i print addressOptions in html file with Knockout Js?

Comment: I have to do that today. Did you succeed ?

Comment: @PolRavalitera did you did that???

Comment: @AsadKhan wow, can't remember. i'll look into it, but not now.